# Need to enable CRLF on old line printer connected to RHEL

Tags: linux, printing, cups

My old green-bar line printer needs a <CR> character along with the <LF> at the end of line to print correctly. Here's how I set it up, using a JetDirect box.

```
# lpadmin -p lp2new -E -v socket://192.168.0.229
```

In CUPS (Common Unix Printing System) I am thinking there has got to be an option I can set in order to enable that. So, something like:

```
 # lpoptions -plp2new -o crlf=true
 # lpoptions -plp2new -o carriage-return=true
```

...but I tried both of these; they are not working. Anyone know the "secret code"?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but there is a suitable option available provided you choose the `texttotext` cups filter. If you use the `cups` gui `localhost:631` to *Add Printer*, you get to a form where you can select the *Make:*. Select *Generic*, click *continue*, and in the next form choose the *Model:* *Generic Text-Only Printer (en)*, and continue.

In the resulting *Set Default Options*, click *Options Installed* and there is a form entry for *Characters to send for a New Line:* where you can select
*Carriage Return and Line Feed (CR + LF) (DOS/Windows style)*.

The equivalent setting is

```
lpoptions -ptest -o NewlineCharacters=CRLF
```

but for this to be available you will have to set the `texttotext` filter ppd first from the command line using `lpadmin`:

```
lpadmin -ptest -m drv:///cupsfilters.drv/textonly.ppd
```

Comment: Thanks; I guess I need to figure out how to add the texttotext filter to the textonly.ppd which I found online. It was not on my RHEL 8.3 system to begin with.

It would also probably help me to learn how to "compile" drivers into PPD files, although the info I have found suggests that this functionality is going away. Any more thoughts?

Comment: The texttotext filter is probably in the textonly.pdd you found. See the paragraph beginning TEXTTOTEXT in the cups [github](https://github.com/OpenPrinting/cups-filters). Perhaps the ppd kept the name for compatibility: *"The texttotext filter replaces the former textonly filter."*